# React-Admin conditional styling with ReferenceField issue

Tags: reactjs, formatting, material-ui, conditional-statements, react-admin

I need to add some conditional styling to a ChipField inside a ReferenceField. I followed the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html) for Conditional Formatting step by step. It works when I don't have ReferenceField but not working with any field inside RefereneField.
Is there any suggestion to solve this?
Here are my codes:

```html
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    green: {backgroundColor: '#00a65a' },
    red: { backgroundColor: '#f39c12' },
    blue: { backgroundColor: '#00c0ef' },
});

const MyTextField = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    const isOnhold = v => v.toUpperCase() === 'ON HOLD';
    const isInprogress = v => v.toUpperCase() === 'IN PROGRESS';
    const isCompleted = v => v.toUpperCase() === 'COMPLETED';
    console.log("props is = " + props.record[props.source]);
    console.log("isOnhold "+isOnhold(props.record[props.source]));
    console.log("isInprogress "+isInprogress(props.record[props.source]));
    console.log("isCompleted "+isCompleted(props.record[props.source]));
    return (
    <ChipField 
        className={classnames({
            [classes.red]: isOnhold(props.record[props.source]),
            [classes.blue]: isInprogress(props.record[props.source]),
            [classes.green]: isCompleted(props.record[props.source]),
        })}
        {...props} 
    />
    );
};

MyTextField.defaultProps = ChipField.defaultProps;
export const TaskList = props => (
    <List filters={<TaskFilter />} {...props} exporter={exporter}>
        <CustomizableDatagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="taskName" label="Name" />
            <ReferenceField source="taskstatusId" reference="taskstatus" label="Status">
                <MyTextField source="tStatus" label="Status"/>
            </ReferenceField>
        </CustomizableDatagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue is on your MyTextField component

```js
<ReferenceField source="taskstatusId" reference="taskstatus" label="Status">
    <MyTextField source="tStatus" label="Status"/>
</ReferenceField>
  
  
<ReferenceField source="taskstatusId" reference="taskstatus" label="Status">
  <MyTextField optionValue="id" optionText="tStatus" label="Status"/>
</ReferenceField>
```

The inner component according to the documenation will use by default **id** as the OptionValue and **name** as the OptionText. The issue maybe is related that your not on the proper way referencing the values